# Getting cookies with duplicate names (Python Selenium)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I use selenium to login to a website, but the website contains two cookies which I get one of them before login and I gain another noe after login , and they have the same name like : `JSESSIONID: XXX; JSESSIONID: XXX`, how can I get both of them or I can choose one form them.

I use the get_cookies method and only get the cookie before login and can't get another one so I can't use that cookie to imitate login.

Is there any solution?

Comment: This is because I get the cookies too fast so I didn't get all of them, I add a time.sleep and the problem get solved.

Comment: Great. You could post your finding to share with the community...